Third term in the free Lie ring
I'm working with the Lie algebra of the free group: $$\mathscr{L}(F_n) = \oplus_{d=1}^{\infty} \mathscr{L}_d(F_n),$$ where $\mathscr{L}_d(F_n) = \gamma_d(F_n) / \gamma_{d+1}(F_n)$ and $\gamma_d(F_n)$ is the $d$th term in the lower central series.
By a theorem of Magnus and Witt, $\mathscr{L}(F_n) \cong L(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ the free Lie ring. This makes the lower degree terms easy to see:

$\mathscr{L}_1(F_n) = F_n / [F_n, F_n] \cong \mathbb{Z}^n = L_1(\mathbb{Z}^n)$

$\mathscr{L}_2(F_n) = [F_n, F_n] / [[F_n, F_n], F_n]$. This is isomorphic to $L_2(\mathbb{Z}^n)$, which contains all things you get by bracketing degree 1 terms in $L(\mathbb{Z}^n)$:
$$[x,y] = x \otimes y - y \otimes x,$$
so it's easy to see $L_2(\mathbb{Z}^n) \cong \wedge^2 \mathbb{Z}^n$.


We get the isomorphism $\mathscr{L}_2(F_n) \rightarrow \wedge^2 \mathbb{Z}^n$ by sending $[x,y] \mapsto [x] \wedge [y]$, where $[x]$ is its abelianization.
How can we describe $\mathscr{L}_3(F_n) \cong L_3(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ in a similar way? It would be great to have a description as a $\mathbb{Z}$-vector space with maps from $\mathscr{L}_3(F_n)$ and $L_3(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ into it.

I found it! On page 608 of "On the group-homological description of the
second Johnson homomorphism" by Yuji Yokomizo, we get $\mathscr{L}_3 \cong \wedge^2 \mathbb{Z}^n \otimes \mathbb{Z}^n / \wedge^3 \mathbb{Z}^n$. This is given by the surjective homomorphism  $\wedge^2 \mathbb{Z}^n \otimes \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathscr{L}_3$: $$(a \wedge b) \otimes c \mapsto [[a,b],c]$$ with kernel $\wedge^3 \mathbb{Z}^n$.
